# SQL query multiple values with the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table.

| pin | checktime | sn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15000 | 2022-04-03 07:00:00 | SRO |
| 15000 | 2022-04-03 08:00:00 | SRO |
| 15000 | 2022-04-03 18:42:52 | SRO |
| 15001 | 2022-04-04 09:42:52 | SRO |
| 15001 | 2022-04-04 15:20:33 | SRO |
| 15003 | 2022-04-05 23:42:52 | SRO |
| 15003 | 2022-04-06 07:00:52 | SRO |

I need the following output

| pin | checkin | checkout | sn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15000 | 2022-04-03 08:00:00 | 2022-04-03 18:42:52 | SRO |
| 15001 | 2022-04-04 09:42:52 | 2022-04-04 15:20:33 | SRO |
| 15003 | 2022-04-05 23:42:52 | 2022-04-06 07:00:52 | SRO |

I've done inner joins to get the result, but it's too slow, any other solutions?

dates must be grouped in a 24-hour range

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have 2 records for each `pin`, and the minimal is always the checkin while the maximal is always checkout? If so, you can try something like that:

```
SELECT
  pin
  ,MIN(checktime) AS checkin
  ,MAX(checktime) AS checkout
  ,sn
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY pin, sn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have some more questions,
How do I group it every 24 and how could I take the maximum checkin date?